# Android Kotlin Safe-Args Navigating back to Fragment without passing arguments again

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-safe-args

For easiest explanation I have 3 fragments.

The first fragment the user will enter languages they want to learn and this data is then passed to the next fragment to update the titles of the table to the current languages. This part I have managed to do successfully using safe args.

However, when you navigate off this fragment to the third fragment and try navigating back you need to pass the arguments again but they have already previously been set on the inital fragment and passed, therefor it will throw an error for not passing the arugments on destination fragment.

Is there someting I have missed or another way to pass data between the fragments that I can use to get around this issue?

Comment: `findNavController().popBackStack()`